# Is it possible to connect to MsolService (powershell) using self signed certificate?

Tags: powershell, office365

maybe some of you faced a similar task: I need to connect to MsolService (Office 365) module using powerhsell, one **prerequisite is to use *certificate***.

I was able to do it with different Microsoft modules such as AzureAD and ExchangeOnline. But cannot find a way to do it with MsolService..

For AzureAD andExchangeOnline I use these cmdlets:

```
Connect-AzureAD –TenantId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" –ApplicationId "XXXXXXXXXXX" –CertificateThumbprint "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbprint "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -AppId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx" -ShowBanner:$false -Organization "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

How can I authenticate to MSolService using cert? :)

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way would be to connect through Microsoft Graph API. But it seems that it does not work with Connect-MSOnline (even though the documentation says so[Connect-MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/connect-msolservice?view=azureadps-1.0)). The following thread suggests that Microsoft is aware of the problem, but is not planning on fixing it: [GITHUB Thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/246). I've tried to connect through Graph API and did not get it to work.